# Textbox or Textarea with Multiple Dynamic Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, terminal-emulator

Is there anyway to create a web based `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>` that is capable of dynamically adding fields to itself so that the user can tab through the available fiends and enter form data?

I've searched around and found a terminal emulator that nearly does what I need.  In the below pictured demo, the user enters `SCHEDL` into the textarea and presses the tab button.  Once the tab button is pressed the program checks the command, in this case `SCHEDL`, and finds available fields associated with the command. It then populates the textarea with fields that can be typed into and tabbed through.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some example code would make the context better.

Comment: That's a great question and of course I deleted pretty much everything I've been fiddling with. I started out with a div that looks like a textarea with a single, dynamically expanding textbox for the initial command. On tab the js would check the command and add text boxes from an array. I feel like this would probably be the best option but the process seemed tedious. Granted I need to expand my education of js and arrays.

Comment: Please note that "textbox" in HTML has non-sense: is it an `<input type="text">` tag? Same issue applies to "div that looks like a textarea": is it a `<div contenteditable="true">` element? I think we can not give you an answer because the question is far too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a prototype of what you're looking for. I used an input tag but that could easily be replaced with textarea.

Anyway, to achieve this;

1. Create a Model. I thought of using a JSON object as it we could model it to be a
   hierarchy of commands and sub/parameters.
2. Capture the "TAB" click when the input field is selected.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.terminal', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // do something if tab is clicked
    }
});
```

3. Then compare the value of your input field through the model by using `$.each()`
4. If it matches, loop through SUB property and add them to the textbox. `inputField.val(inputField.val() + " " + v2.Name);`

---

**Run the snippet below.** Try typing SCHEDL then press TAB. Try typing TEST then press TAB.

```js
var commandJson = {
  "Commands": [{
      "Name": "SCHEDL",
      "Sub": [{
          "Name": "From:"
        },
        {
          "Name": "To:"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "TEST",
      "Sub": [{
          "Name": "A:"
        },
        {
          "Name": "B:"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', '.terminal', function(e) {
    var inputField = $(this);
    var inputValue = inputField.val();
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // loop through the COMMANDS
      $.each(commandJson.Commands, function(k1, v1) {
        if (inputValue.toUpperCase() == v1.Name) {

          // if the command matches the input, loop through SUB and display in textbox
          $.each(v1.Sub, function(i2, v2) {
            inputField.val(inputField.val() + " " + v2.Name);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.terminal {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input class="terminal" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is amazing, never thought about a json string. I'll have to play with this more. Thank you!